Why is my API returning bad requests? Angular / C# full stack application
My application is basically a gamified social media site.
My frontend is an Angular application that is trying to ping a C# backend.
I have a Microsoft SQL Server that I am using and managing via Dbeaver.
I am using all Azure services to connect the whole application.
I created/populated the database, migrated it with EF Core, and made sure all the controllers and everything are working. I can run the backend and ping the API and get accurate responses with multiple methods, so I know that the database is working at least. The local API works via swagger. I cannot seem to pinpoint what the disconnect is between my frontend and backend.
I used dotnet user-secret set and created a user secret with the connection string in it.
builder.Configuration.AddUserSecrets<Program>();
var cs = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Usr");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<CosminisOfficialDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(cs));

I added a guid to the property group for the user secret so the environment should have it
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UserSecretsId>USER_GUID</UserSecretsId>
</PropertyGroup>

I don't think it is even my code (yet) though... I don't think it gets that far.
When I click the URL on my Azure web app, I just get a 400 even though all my code should be working at least on the backend. I am not sure what it could be and I have just been at this and making no progress. Can anyone think of what I might be missing?
Also relevant:
When I look at my application logs when I try to make simple requests to just the API itself, my logger spits out a bunch of html and it says this:
My actual API name should be APP_NAME-Ithinkmysubscribercode.eastus-01.azurewebsites.net/
but then the log says APP_NAME:80 and it doesn't have the subscriber code or eastus-01.azurewebsites.net part.... Why would it be requesting it from a totally different URL? I am also using port 1433 and not port 80 anywhere.



400
Bad Request




Requested URL
https://APP_NAME:80/companions/GetAll


Physical Path
C:\home\site\wwwroot\companions\GetAllRequested


URL
https://APP_NAME:80/companions/GetAll


Physical Path
C:\home\site\wwwroot\companions\GetAll



I have been trying everything I can think of including azure tools to figure out where there is a disconnect. I used AI and asked friends and have been looking things up online constantly for like 3 days now....
Per request: my program.cs program
using DataAccess.Entities;
using CustomExceptions;

using System.Data.SqlClient;
using DataAccess;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Services;
using Controllers;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("MyAllowAllHeadersPolicy",
        builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("*")
                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
});

builder.Services.AddDbContext<CosminisOfficialDBContext>(options=> options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("CosminiDBConnectionString")));

builder.Services.AddScoped<ICompanionDAO, CompanionRepo>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IFriendsDAO, FriendsRepo>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserDAO, UserRepo>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IPostDAO, PostRepo>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICommentDAO, CommentRepo>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IResourceGen, ResourceRepo>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ILikeIt, LikeRepo>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<Interactions, InteractionRepo>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<ResourceServices>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<CompanionServices>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<FriendServices>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<UserServices>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<PostServices>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<CommentServices>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<LikeServices>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<InteractionService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<LotteryService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<BattleServices>();

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

app.UseCors("MyAllowAllHeadersPolicy");

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

From my environment.ts and environment.prod.ts that are the same:
export const environment = 
{
  production: false, 
  api: 'https://cosminis-fge8geh4gjfdf4ca.eastus-01.azurewebsites.net',
  auth:
  {
    domain: "dev-lj8y5w8u.us.auth0.com",
    clientId: "Lq2lP0EYqPCAqzFtXLYdphFwobokBBw0",
    redirectUri: window.location.origin
  }
};



Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
